# I need KQL query from AzureDiagnostics to return SQL text

Tags: kql, azure-log-analytics

I have the following KQL query which returns top 3 **query_id** by total CPU time from Log Analytics.

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where TimeGenerated >= ago( 1h )
and Category == 'QueryStoreRuntimeStatistics'
| summarize total_cpu_time = sum(cpu_time_d) by query_id_d
| top 3 by total_cpu_time desc ;
```

| query_id_d | total_cpu_time |
| --- | --- |
| 10,985 | 293,881,252 |
| 9,527 | 286,838,329 |
| 10,163 | 178,836,543 |

So, how can I now import the **SQL statement text** from the source database for each query_id, so I can include that column in the result as if I were using Azure SQL QueryStore directly?

For example, here is the desired result:

| query_id_d | total_cpu_time | query_text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10,985 | 293,881,252 | SELECT * FROM Customer ... |
| 9,527 | 286,838,329 | SELECT CustomerID ... |
| 10,163 | 178,836,543 | SELECT A, B, C FROM ... |